# Order a query based on comparison of associated records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

```
class Man
  has_many :sons

  # id
end

class Son
  belongs_to :man

  # id, man_id, age
end
```

I was to retrieve men from the DB and I want them ordered based on the age of their oldest son. Here's an example.

```
first_man = Man.create
first_man.sons.create(age: 10)
first_man.sons.create(age: 5)

second_man = Man.create
second_man.sons.create(age: 20)
second_man.sons.create(age: 5)

third_man = Man.create
third_man.sons.create(age: 19)
third_man.sons.create(age: 8)

Man.order('[some order]').to_a
=> [second_man, third_man, first_man]
```

How do I get ActiveRecord to do this?

**Edit**

I get invalid SQL when I try to do `Man.joins(:sons).order("sons.age DESC").uniq`.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
       LINE 1: ...sons"."man_id" = "men"."id"  ORDER BY sons...
                                                                    ^
       : SELECT  DISTINCT "men".* FROM "men" INNER JOIN "sons" ON "sons"."man_id" = "men"."id"  ORDER BY sons.age DESC LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tried it but i guess this should work

```
 Man.includes(:sons).order("sons.age").to_a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Man.joins(:sons).order('sons.age DESC').uniq
```

**Updated**

Maybe this will help but is's ugly

```
Son.order('age DESC').map(&:man).uniq
```

Comment: @Rafa: what are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised about the time, he was first. Hence I deleted my answer.